# Read binary and txt File - 1 byte at a time

Tags: c, io, binaryfiles, file-handling, fgetc

I am trying to write a code which reads 1 byte (ideal goal is n bytes but starting with 1 byte - so for n bytes if its easier please suggest)

Below is the code I have attempted to read 1 byte at a time and output it in hex format. But all get is bunch of FFFF

```
    FILE *fp;
    int stringlength,i;

    /* File can be txt or .bin */
    fp = fopen("TestFile3.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        puts("Error: Input file cannot be read");
        return -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        size_t i, strlength, lengthOfFile,c;
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        lengthOfFile = ftell(fp);
        printf("length of File is ---- %d \n", lengthOfFile);
        while (lengthOfFile)
        {
            c = fgetc(fp);
            printf("%c", c);
            lengthOfFile--;
        }
        putchar('\n');

    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);` - what do you think this doing?

Comment: you seeked to the end of the file, then keep trying to read, which means you're reading nothing but EOF....

Comment: Having jumped to the end of the file, you're only going to get EOF when you read more data, aren't you?

Comment: Just as a point of style, you don't need an `else` when the previous code block exits.

Comment: Thank u all for the pointer - yes I realize the mistake

Comment: To read *n* bytes, take a look at [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread)

Comment: You didn't show `c`, but if it is `int c` the whole thing can be done with `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {...}`

Comment: `c` has to be `int`, `size_t` is a very wrong type. And read about format string syntax and correct arguments.

Comment: @Olaf - Thanks - will keep it mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);` to reset the file pointer before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're also opening the file in "text" mode:

```
fp = fopen("TestFile3.txt", "r");
```

Per the [C Standard, section 7.19.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into
>   lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a
>   terminating new-line character.  Whether the last line requires a
>   terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. Characters
>   may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to
>   conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host
>   environment. **Thus, there need not be a one- to-one correspondence
>   between the characters in a stream and those in the external
>   representation.**

Using `fseek()/ftell()` doesn't return the number of bytes readable from a text stream.

You need to open the file in binary mode if you want to read every byte per the size of the file:

```
fp = fopen("TestFile3.txt", "rb");
```

Finally, the use of `fseek()/ftell()` isn't reliable on binary files either, because, again per the C standard, 7.19.9.2:

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a
>   whence value of SEEK_END

Given that, you can't reliably use `fseek()/ftell()` to find out how big a binary file is, either.  And yes, examples do exist.

To reliably read all the bytes in a file, @Weather Vane posted one way to do that in the comments.